# How to ask for another input if the required options are not entered?

Tags: java

I know this is an easy question, but I am new to Java and am so lost. All that is left to do in my program is output a message saying something like "Invalid input, try again" at the end of each case in my program if the user does not enter either a yes or a no and return to the point where it asks for another calculation. I know it's elementary and I looked for an answer the best I could but I simply don't know enough of the java terminology. If you could help me I would appreciate it so much!

P.S.It was pointed out to me that my variables should not begin with capital letters, I am aware and will not do it in the future.

```
System.out.println(" The purpose of this program is to calculate the speed of sound through several mediums.\n The program user will input a distance in feet followed by a mediumd and the program will output the speed in feet per second and miles per hour\n");
//declare variables

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

final double Air = 1126.1;

final double Water = 4603.2;

final double Steel = 20013.3;

final double Earth = 22967.4;

double OneFootPerSecond = .68181818182;

double Distance;

double AirSpeed;

double WaterSpeed;

double SteelSpeed;

double EarthSpeed;

boolean shouldContinue = true;

while (shouldContinue == true){ 

System.out.print(" What is the distance in feet:" );
//ask the user to input variables


    while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()){
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid numeric value, try again: ");
    keyboard.next();
    }
    Distance =keyboard.nextDouble();
    {
    System.out.print("Input the media: Air, Water, Steel, or Earth: ");
    String Input = keyboard.next();   



    switch(Input.toLowerCase())

     {

        case "air":
        AirSpeed = Distance/Air;
        System.out.print("\n \nThe time to for sound to travel ");
        System.out.print(Distance);
        System.out.print(" feet through AIR" +"\n");
        System.out.printf("%.6f", AirSpeed);
        System.out.print(" seconds or ");
        System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Air);
        System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
        System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
        String Another = keyboard.next();
        Another.toLowerCase();
       if (Another.equals("no")){
           shouldContinue = false;
                          }
      if (!Another.equals("no"))
          if (!Another.equals("yes"))
          {System.out.print("Invalid.");


          }


        break;



 case "water":
        WaterSpeed = Distance/Water;
        System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
        System.out.print(Distance);
        System.out.print(" feet through WATER" +"\n");
        System.out.printf("%.6f",WaterSpeed);
        System.out.print(" seconds or ");
        System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Water);
        System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
        System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
        Another = keyboard.next();
        Another.toLowerCase();
         if (Another.equals("yes")){
           shouldContinue = false;

       }
break;

 case "steel":
        SteelSpeed = Distance/Steel;
        System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
        System.out.print(Distance);
        System.out.print(" feet through STEEL" +"\n");
        System.out.printf("%.6f",SteelSpeed);
        System.out.print(" seconds or ");
        System.out.printf("%.1f",  OneFootPerSecond*Steel);
        System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
        System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
        Another = keyboard.next();
        Another.toLowerCase();
         if (Another.equals("yes")){
           shouldContinue = false;

       }
break;     

      case "earth":
        EarthSpeed = Distance/Water;
        System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
        System.out.print(Distance);
        System.out.print(" feet through EARTH" +"\n");
        System.out.printf("%.6f",EarthSpeed);
        System.out.print(" seconds or ");
        System.out.printf("%.1f",  OneFootPerSecond*Earth);
        System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
        System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
        Another = keyboard.next();
        Another.toLowerCase();
         if (Another.equals("yes")){
           shouldContinue = false;

       }
break;
default :
        System.out.print("Invalid. Re-run the program. ");                  
 break;                      
    }
   }
```

Comment: GOTO LABEL (no really, java is not meant to be used like this. It has all this fancy object stuff, like methods. You shall divide the code into separate methods, it will be easier to work with and will save you a lot of time.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty easy solution would be a small method for it

let me show you a small example:

```
public class Main {
    public static Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String... args) {
        // ...
        switch(somthing) {
        case "something":
            // ...
            if (!shallContinue()) return;
            break;
        case "something else":
            // ...
            if (!shallContinue()) return;
            break;
        default:
            // ...
            if (!shallContinue()) return;
        }
    }

    public static boolean shallContinue() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
            switch (reader.nextLine().toLowerCase()) {
            case "yes":
                return true;
            case "no":
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basicly you call a function and depending on the result you just terminate. That function then does the actual user communication